# Can't mount image of NTFS partition created by ddrescue

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, ntfs, ddrescue

I've used ddrescue successfully in the past but I'm having no luck this time. Usually, I make an image of the partition, run a fsck or whatever else on the image to fix file system errors, mount it and I'm good to go. However, this image is not able to be mounted. When I try to mount it in Linux, using...

```
mount -t ntfs -o loop image.img /mnt/img
```

I get this message...

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop/0': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop/0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
```

I have tried with `-t ntfs-3g` as well and it makes no difference. I've even tried mounting the image in Windows so I could run `chkdsk` on it but it shows as a raw volume. I have tried `testdisk` and it doesn't see a proper NTFS partition. One thing that is odd in `testdisk is that it is showing the drive size as 317 / 295 GiB.

I'm still trying to figure out testdisk but any help would be appreciated. I really don't have a good understanding of hard drives so I may have omitted something that's important in figuring this out. If so please let me know and I will update the question. Thanks!

-- Adding output from `sfdisk -l` --

```
Device Boot Start End #cyls #blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 0+ 12- 13- 102400 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2   12+ 38650- 38639- 310360064 7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3   38651 38912 262 2104515 c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda4   0 - 0 0 0 Empty
```

I need data from sda2.

Comment: How big is the disk you are cloning and how big is the HD?  What is the output of *fdisk -l*?  You may also take a look at *dd_rescue*.

Comment: @jmreicha I added the output from _sfdisk -l_ to the question above. For some reason fdisk just freezes but sfdisk worked fine.

Comment: Take a look at this, http://rackerhacker.com/2010/12/14/mounting-a-raw-partition-file-made-with-dd-or-dd_rescue-in-linux/.  This guy says you may have to mount the partition at the offset in order to get it to work correctly.